# Scala IDE 4.1 and SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-macros, scala-ide

We have a project that uses Scala macros. Scala IDE 4.1 supports [Scopes](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/features/scalacompiler/index.html) to ease compilation of projects with macros. However, when I use `sbt eclipse`, the generated project does not show macros as a source folder and does not create separate outputs for each source folder. 
Is this a missing feature in SBT? Is there any workaround?

My `build.sbt` file looks like this:

```
name in ThisBuild := "Test"

organization in ThisBuild := "org.test"

version in ThisBuild := "0.1.0"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test",
    "junit" % "junit" % "4.11"
)
```

Comment: What is your project layout? Macros should be located in their own project, this way sbteclipse generates the correct Eclipse files.

Comment: you mean a multi-project configuration in SBT? To me it looks like that Eclipse IDE 4.1 just support macros in a separate `macros` folder and I thought based on the name of the folder should figure it out.

Comment: You should show your sbt configuration. You need to specify this `macros` folder as a separate source folder, otherwise Eclipse can't recognize it as such (or you do the configuration only in Eclipse).

Comment: I updated the question with my build.sbt. You mean by using something like: `unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "extra-src"`?